# How to create application which is display message in specific time and day in android

Tags: android, service, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating app which contain.

```
-> time like 2:30 AM

-> Repeat like sat,sun
```

User is **dynamic add time and repeating value**.For example we have 10 record with different value.

So how i can display message at particular time and schedule period.I think **Alarm Manager** and **services** is best.But i don't know how to used.

How can i trigger different alarm in particular day and time.

please give me some guideline.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh no i want create alarm type app which give me message when alarm trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done this task.

Using **AlarmManager** with **services**.

@chaitanya Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

yes. you have to use AlarmManager for it. Below is best link with example of AlarmManager http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651

Comment: i have Manny time and day so how i can display message as specific time and day in background

Comment: you can set specific time & day at alarm manager it will notify at your device. Mention link has explained the example how to set the alarm from app.

Comment: first it is not work in background and second thing is if i have 50 record then i have to set 50 Alarm manager.